# Working with multiple pages in apache cordova and vs2013

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova

I was introduced to the idea of building mobile apps with apache cordova and visual studio 2013 today by my superior. The challenge that first came to my mind was

since its a single paged technology(index.html), how will I go around multiple pages(navigating to other pages).

How do i work with data access and what kind of data access is allowed (talking about microsoft sql server, Linq queries and the like).

Answer (score 0):

While this question is very broad, you might want to look into one of the several SPA (single-page application) frameworks out there.

I'd personally recommend a framework like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) combined with [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) to get yourself started.

Hybrid apps developed for Cordova will likely benefit most from a RESTful API through which you can communicate with your server using whichever technology you prefer (sounds like .NET, here).  WCF has several [ways to establish a RESTful API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412172%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for your phone app.

Best of luck, and I hope this helps.